# Python, importing from same module: ImportError: cannot import name 'blah', __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python

Very easy issue to replicate. My current setup is:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    run.py
```

In my `__init.py__` I have:

```py
blah = 4
```

And in my `run.py` I have:

```py
from package import blah


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(blah)
```

I simply run it with `python run.py`. But I am getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'blah'`.

How come I am not being able to import a variable from my package? I know how to workaround it, I am rather interested in knowing the reason for the error.

Comment: Why such case raised `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxxx`?

Comment: @LiuXiMin yes that is my question

Comment: If you aren't trying to run this as a package (even though that is how you have it set up) you should just make 2 files: run.py and variables.py and inside of run.py just do `from variables import blah`

Comment: Yea that is true, but I would rather have ```from . import blah```. Even though that does not work. I wasn't indeed trying to run it as a package. But what do you mean _even though that is how you have it set up_ ?

Comment: You are trying to import from `__init__.py` without explicitly calling `__init__.py` in your import. This can only be done if you are using this as a package. If you are running as scripts, you might as well call `__init__.py` variables.py. You are also trying to `import from package` but `run.py` has no concept of `package` as it is currently structured, and in fact at this point `package` is just a directory with python scripts in it.

Comment: See my edits to address rearchitecture,.

Answer (score 3):

You are clearly trying to execute this as a package, but you are running "run.py" as if it were a standard python script. `run.py` does not have a concept of `module` in the sense of how you are trying to run it. You need to re-architect your design here. in the package `module` `run.py` would be a module (these are your naming conventions here). So `module` is the package, and `run.py` is a module. You then need a `__main__.py` to execute this as a package and you need to change your run.py:

`run.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from module1 import blah

def run():
    print(blah)
```

`__main__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from module1 import run

def main():
    run.run() # run is the module name, and run is also the function name so we execute with run.run

main()
```

`__init__.py`:

```
blah = 4
```

directory structure:

module1/
 - `__init__.py`
 - `__main__.py`
 - `run.py`

to execute (outside of `module1`):

```
[dkennetz@nodem103  fun]$ python3.5 -m module1
4
```

If you do not want to make this a package, you should simply create a directory called `package` and inside you can make `run.py` and `variables.py`.

variables.py:

```
blah=4
blahblah=8
blahblahblah=12
```

run.py:

```
from variables import blah
print(blah)
```

prints 4

if you changed run.py to:

```
from variables import blah, blahblah

print(blah)
print(blahblah)

[dkennetz@nodem103  package]$ python3.5 run.py
4
8
```

Or you can import all variables by changing run.py to:

```
from variables import *
print(blah)
print(blahblah)
print(blahblahblah) # if this was added to variables.py as 12
```

It returns:

```
[dkennetz@nodem103  package]$ python3.5 run.py
4
8
12
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to run it as a package. I will instead re-architect this to be able to run is as a module.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are running `python run.py` from within the directory `package`. Python then looks for a package (a directory) or a module (`.py` file) named "package" *inside* that directory, but neither exists. As it cannot import the symbol `blah`, it raises an `ImportError`.

Comment: So then how would I import ```blah``` to my script if not with ```from module import blah```?

Comment: That actually worked. But indeed, that is bad style indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to import from the module you are in.

Here is my structure

```
[syspath]
$ tree
.
├── mod
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── run.py
└── orun.py

1 directory, 3 files

[syspath]
$ cat mod/run.py 
#from mod import blah
from . import blah

print(blah)

[syspath]
$ cat orun.py 
from mod import blah

print(blah)

[syspath]
$ python3 orun.py 
4

[syspath]
$ python3 -m mod.run
4
```

Being within the `module` directory you are effectively a part of the module and can't import it, you can however reference it as a sibling but only if you are being run as a part of the module, as in `python3 -m mod.run` the `-m` is *run this as a **module***.

A bit more of an understanding, python `import` looks for entries available in `sys.path`,
Here are the `sys.path`s found in the `orun.py` (outside of the module), and `mod/run.py` within the module.

```
[syspath]
$ python3 orun.py 
['~/syspath',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

[syspath]
$ python3 mod/run.py 
['~/syspath/mod',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

As you see when you are inside of `mod` you can't find another mod inside of it.

Try adding a new file in the directory with the same name `module.py` and put a different value for `blah` and you will see the code execute with that value.

```
[syspath]
$ tree
.
├── mod
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mod.py
│   └── run.py
└── orun.py

1 directory, 4 files

[syspath]
$ cat mod/mod.py 
blah = 40

[syspath]
$ python3 mod/run.py 
40
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, package and module are two different concept. module is single py file and package must be a dir which must contain `__init__.py`.

`__init__.py` is for `packages`, when you run run.py in package dir, package dir can not be treated as `a package`, and package dir of course are not `module`. So it raised the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxxx`.

> When a regular package is imported, this`__init__.py` file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace.

[5. The import system — Python 3.7.4rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages)